# Swift cast without specifying generic type

Tags: swift, generics, casting, bolts-framework

I'm trying to create a universal error handler for my application and to make matters even more complicated I'm using an event bus to pass a task around so I can't specify the type on compile-time. I'm trying to do the following:

```
let apiTask = data.object as! Task // Option 1
let apiTask = data.object as! Task<AnyObject> // Option 2

apiTask!.continueWith { (task) in
    if(task.cancelled || task.faulted) {
        self.isInError = true
    } else {
        self.isInError = false
    }
}
```

**Option 1** gives a compile time error saying the generic type TResut of Task cannot be inferred.
**Option 2** causes a runtime error saying `Task<SpecificType> cannot be caster to Task<AnyObject>`

I have the same implementation in Java where it seems you don't need to specify the generic type there. `Task<TResult>` could be potentially any type so I can't specify it in the method above. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't actually want a generic type. Generic types exist to specify, at compile time, exactly the sort of type information you are trying to erase. If you almost always want to ignore the generic parameter, then you should make a non-generic type. If, however, you usually use that information, you can still ignore it in certain methods: you'll just have to make those methods generic anyway:

```
func doSomething<T>(to: Task<T>) {
    //Do whatever you want that doesn't involve `T`.
    //You still have to make this method generic so it accepts any type of `Task`.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that as the `Task` is stored in `data.object`. Now this is not really a safe thing to do but I'm willing to take the risk and try to cast this to a `Task`. Sadly it seems Swift is not allowing that

Comment: So option 1 (changing to a non-generic type) is out. Option 2 it is! Make your universal error handler methods themselves generic, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making Task a protocol (or conform to a protocol)?

```
protocol Task {
    func execute()
}

class SimpleTask<T>: Task {
    let parameter: T
    init(parameter: T) {
        self.parameter = parameter
    }
    func execute() {
        print("executing task with parameter: \(parameter)")
    }
}

func executeTask(task: Task) {
    task.execute()
}

let simpleTask = SimpleTask<Int>(parameter: 1)
executeTask(simpleTask)
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your post on the Bolts-Swift issue tracker and since I don't know if you see my answer there I thought I post it here as well. I'm new to Bolts and also a beginner in Swift but I have a few years experience as a programmer so this is a possible solution I came up with:

I think you could create a class or struct which acts as a wrapper to your actual result. This struct/class only need one variable of type AnyObject. You then use this as the generic type of your tasks. Later you can make acutal checks for the type of the result e. g. by using `if let string = task.result?.result as? String{...}`. See the code below to understand what I mean.

```
func printHelloWorld() {
    doSomething().continueWith() { task in
        print(task.result?.result)
    }
}

func doSomething() -> Task<MyResult> {
    let tcs = TaskCompletionSource<MyResult>()
    ...
    tcs.set(result: MyResult(result: "Hello World" as AnyObject))
    ...
    return tcs.task
}

struct MyResult {
    var result: AnyObject
}
```

As I said, I'm a beginner in Bolts and Swift and probably there is a better solution. If you already found a better solution, maybe you can post it here and select it as the answer to your question. :)